# Cómo reordenar un data.frame con dos keys una de ellas factor con gather?

Tags: r

Trabajo en reordenar un dataframe de 48 columnas con la siguiente estructura:

```
data.frame(H01=c(23,25),
           V01=c("V","N"),
           H02=c(18,7),
           V02=c("V","V"))
#...
```

El dataset sigue con este patrón hasta "H24" y "V24".
Cada variable "H" es una lectura. hay 24, una por hora. Cada "V" es una variable factor de verificación, utiliza para aceptar o rechazar el dato.

Estoy buscando alguna manera con tidy para que quede de la siguiente forma:

```
data.frame(Hora=c("H01","H01","H02","H02"),
           Verificacion=c("V","N","V","V"),
           Valor=c(23,25,28,7))
```

1 sola columna de todas las horas en forma factor, 1 sola columna para ver si el dato esta validado o no y el valor de la lectura.

He probado doble `gather()` pero , tras varias combinaciones algo me falla. Bien me cruza todas las combinaciones de variables tipo: H01 con V02 por ejemplo que no tienen sentido, o bien la columna de verificación solo contiene los nombres de las variables y no su contenido

hasta ahora he probado:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  gather(Hora, lectura, starts_with("H")) %>%
  gather(Verificacio,"valor_verificacio",starts_with("V"))
```

Comment: En el resultado esperado `[3,3]` dice 28 y creo que debería ser 18, que es el valor de df original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es posible con `gather()` pero sí con [`pivot_longer()`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_longer.html), la función que han creado para reemplazar a `gather()`en la versión 1.0.0 de `tidyr`.

Con el siguiente código obtienes el resultado que buscas. Más abajo pongo una explicación extra.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = everything(),
               names_to = c(".value", "Hora"),
               names_pattern = "(.)(..)") %>% 
  select(Hora, Verificacion = V, Valor = H) %>% 
  arrange(Hora)

# # A tibble: 4 x 3
# Hora  Verificacion Valor
# <chr> <fct>        <dbl>
# 1 01    V               23
# 2 01    N               25
# 3 02    V               18
# 4 02    V                7
```

### Explicación

La primera parte del 'pipeline' usado utiliza `pivot_longer()`. El argumento `cols = everything()` indica que usaremos todas las variables de `df`. Con `names_to = c(".value", "Hora")`, pedimos crear dos tipos de columna, *.value* dependerá de uno o más valores que encontremos en un patrón, y *Hora*, que dependerá de otro patrón.

¿Dónde está el patrón? Lo vamos a proveer con `names_pattern = "(.)(..)"`. Esto resulta muy útil en tu caso porque todos los nombres de columna de tu `df` tienen primero un caracter que indica el tipo de variable y luego dos caracteres que indican el número de observación. Veamos qué obtenemos al correr sólo el `pivot_longer()`.

```r
df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = everything(),
               names_to = c(".value", "Hora"),
               names_pattern = "(.)(..)")

# # A tibble: 4 x 3
# Hora      H V    
# <chr> <dbl> <fct>
# 1 01       23 V    
# 2 02       18 V    
# 3 01       25 N    
# 4 02        7 V
```

Como se esperaba, hemos obtenido una columna con el nombre *Hora*, pero también hemos obtenido dos columnas más, *H* y *V*. La función ha "pivoteado" todas las columnas originales en esas dos. Lo que queda es solamente ordenarla y darle los nombres adecuados. Para ello hice uso de `select()` que me permite al mismo tiempo renombrar y darle orden a las columnas, y `arrange()` para darle orden a las filas (aunque creo que esto último es opcional).

Comment: Vale, perfecto, me ha sido muy útil. Una pregunta adicional que probablemente surja en breves. En caso de tener variables adicionales (tales como una variable date, en la que esta puesto el día de la medida, u otros factores) ¿És posible conservar dichas variables?. He creado un par de variables adicionales , una factor y una Date, tratando de conservarlas a lo largo del proceso, pero no se conservan.

Comment: No he intentado eso, pero imagino que al igual que con `gather()`, indicando un vector o patrón para los nombres de variables a pivotear sería posible (también se puede indicar las columnas a ignorar con la forma `-c(columnax, columnay)`. Si pudieras crear un ejemplo reproducible sería más fácil ayudarte.

Comment: Este seria un ejemplo de una versión ampliada donde hay más variables, con diferentes nombres y patrones de letras pero yo solo quiero matener el `pivot_longer`
 y yo solo quiero agrupar por las variables `H `y `V`, el patrón de los nombres se mantiene:
 `data.frame(
  id=c("0000001","0000001"),
  Long=c(41.4,41.4),
  Lat= c(2.13,2.13), 
  Date=c(as.Date("2018-01-01"),as.Date("2018-01-02")),
  H01=c(23,25),
  V01=c("V","N"),
  H02=c(18,7),
  V02=c("V","V"))`

Comment: Ya esta! hoy me he iluminado, no acaba de entender cómo funcionaba el argumento `cols()`. Creía que solo podía trabajar con problema era con el `name_pattern`, pero la clave estabqa en decirle que variables quiero que excluya de la agregación con `cols()`. Muchísimas gracias por la respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Pude obtener el resultado haciendo los `gather()` de las variables `V` y `H` por separado y después un `cbind()` para reunirlo todo.

```
cbind(
df %>% 
    select(starts_with("H")) %>% 
    gather(Hora, Valor),
df %>% 
  select(starts_with("V")) %>% 
  gather(clave, Verificación)
) %>% 
  select(Hora, Verificación, Valor)

   Hora Verificación Valor
1  H01            V    23
2  H01            N    25
3  H02            V    18
4  H02            V     7
```

De esta forma se evita el problema de la duplicación de valores. Supongo que habrá una solución más consistente, `cbind()` no es de fiar porque si se "desordenan" los valores procederá sin siquiera emitir un warning. Pero en este caso funciona.